# Found GNU make version GNU Make is not for msys (it says: Built for x86_64-unknown-cygwin)

Tags: java, jvm

I tried to build the openjkd source code in Windows 10 , however I got the following error when running " ./configure -with-freetype=/cygdrive/c/Users/jason/Downloads/freetype-2.8.1/freetype-2.8.1 -enable-debug -with-target-bits=64"

"configure: Found GNU make version GNU Make 4.1 at /c/cygwin64/bin/make, but it i                                          s not for msys (it says: Built for x86_64-unknown-cygwin)."

[image]

BTW,I install the make by cygwin, and the issue happened both for jkd 8&9 ,also I just cannot get a  GNU make for msys .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are apparently trying to build on "msys".  Here is what the [Build Instructions](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/raw-file/tip/common/doc/building.html#windows) say about that:

> Windows is the only non-POSIX OS supported by OpenJDK, and as such, requires some extra care. A POSIX support layer is required to build on Windows. For OpenJDK 9, the only supported such layer is Cygwin. (**Msys is no longer supported due to a too old bash**; msys2 and the new Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) would likely be possible to support in a future version but that would require a community effort to implement.)

You also said:

> BTW, I install the make by cygwin

By itself, that won't help.  You actually need to a full install of Cygwin, and use Cygwin to run the builds.  (Not msys or mingw64.)

Comment: Thanks,  the issue fixed switch to cygwin.